# How to proceed further in Putty to get details from parse server

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, putty, bitnami

I am trying to access parse through Putty.....I have successfully opened the Bitnami screen but after that, if I try to type cd apps/parse/htdocs to get the Masterkey and app id it says that no such directory exists. Please help me how can I solve this. please see the screenshot below. I do not know how I should proceed further to get all the details from parse server

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I  too have the exact same problem...if you find an answer please post it here

Comment: I found the solution...type vi opt/bitnami/parse/config.json

Comment: Yes, that really worked, thanks a lot...although I had to type cd opt/bitnami/parse and vi config.json separately

Answer (score 1):

I too encountered the same issue. 
Type cd stack/parse-dashboard/ 
Then vi config.json
You're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

instead of doing `cd apps/parse/htdocs`

just do   `cd stack/parse`

and then `cat config.json`

you will surely get the appid and client id and url of the parse server

Comment: Please try to markdown your answer where it's needed.

Comment: Okay will do next time