# How to connect Android studio 3.6.0 to AWS Parse server? I have already created AES EC2 Parse server instance, but need help to connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform

How to connect Android studio 3.6.0 to AWS Parse server? I have already created AES EC2 Parse server instance, but need help to connect. My Android application with AWS Parse server to save data fetched from user?

I tried to use Androiddevcourse website parse project.zip, but gradle build is failing.

Comment: https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/

Answer (score 0):

First you need to connected to the Bitnami server either by using PuTTY or the command prompt. so you need to create a new  Android Studio project and do the following.

1. Go to your project files and navigate to the Gradle scripts.There you will find 2 build.gradle files
2. Now open the build.gradle Module file.
3. Then insert this:

```
"implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.24.1"
```

The version may change at the time check *https://jitpack.io/#parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android*
inside the

```
-dependencies {}
```

Then open the other build.gradle and add

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

}

and remember to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to your Manifest file.
then create a new java file App(Or any name)
Ps. you do not need to add all the permissions only the one you want to use.

```
import com.parse.Parse;
import android.app.Application;
public class App extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
      .applicationId("YOUR_APP_ID")
      // if defined
      .clientKey("YOUR_CLIENT_KEY")
      .server("http://localhost:1337/parse/")
      .build()
    );
  }
}
```

Enter the above details properly which you found using cmd or PuTTY after connecting to
Bitnami;
see **https://stackoverflow.com/a/62358879/12500013** for further details
Then The custom Application class must be registered in AndroidManifest

```
<application
   android:name=".App"
   ...>
   ...
 </application>
```

According to Network security configuration -

Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.

Also have a look at - **https://koz.io/android-m-and-the-war-on-cleartext-traffic/**
So put this inside the **Manifest** file:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

**Then final and most important make sure that the API which you are using

must be the same as the device which you are testing the App**

Comment: How is your answer related to AES EC2 Parse server? Please add a bit of information to pick the asker up where they currently are.

Comment: The asker who is trying to connect to the AES EC2 Parse Server will get this!